# How to run a test twice in pytest

Tags: python-2.7, pytest

I have three tests in a module

```
def test_A(fixture, test_param): 
def test_B(fixture, test_param):
def test_c(fixture, test_param):
```

I have a requirement to run the test in following order:

```
def test_A()
def test_C()
def test_B()
def test_C()
```

`test_C()` should run two times, after `test_A()` and also after `test_B()`.
I have marked

```
@pytest.mark.run(after='test_A')
@pytest.mark.run(after='test_B')
def test_C()
```

but `test_c()` is only once after `test_A()` or `Test_B()`.

Answer (score 1):

Factor out `test_C` and run it twice under different names:

```
def _test_C():
    …code for test C…

def test_A():
    …

def test_C()
    _test_C()

def test_B()
    …

def test_C2()
    _test_C()
```